# FireBird, вызов хранимой процедуры результат которой выборка и обновление

Tags: база-данных, delphi, firebird, interbase

Есть хранимая процедура, которая во-первых **выдает результат выборку данных**, и во-вторых **обновляет поля**.
Есть два вида вызова внутренней процедуры и оба не подходят:

> 1)    Селективный вызов (через “select”), что в принципе мне позволяет
>   получить выборку, но в таком случае нет “commit” для “update”.
>   2)    Через «EXECUTE PROCEDURE», в таком случае наборот, будет “commit”
>   для “update”, но вместо выборки будет всего одна строка..

- Можно ли так вызвать процедуру, чтоб и“commit” для “update” и выборка?
- Или нужно процедуру разделять на “update” и “выборку”?
- Или уже из одной процедуры вызывать другую (например разделить на 2 процедуры: “выборка” и “update” - таким образом из delphi вызывать “выборку”, а из нее вызывать “update”)? Но хотелось ветаки иметь одну процедуру.

Comment: Дайте текст хранимой процедуры и скажите какие компоненты используете. Тогда я вам напишу как вызвать через select - потому что вызывать надо как раз через select.

Answer (score 1):

1. Явно стартовать транзакцию, причем не read only.
2. Выполнить SELECT с чтением на клиента всех записей.
3. Явно выполнить коммит.

Подробности зависят от компонентов, которые вы используете.

Comment: Коммит сразу не поможет. Надо сначала все записи профетчить. А потом уже коммит.

Comment: Профетчить все записи может и сам DataSet, без дополнительных действий со стороны программиста, но это действительно нужно иметь ввиду.

Comment: Как правило в компонентах доступа сразу фетчатся не все записи, а буфер, поэтому если принудительно не делать fetchAll или while not query.eof do query.next - будет плавающая ошибка. Пока записей мало все ок, а если возвращает больше, чем в буфер помещается - для них процедура просто-напросто не будет выполнена. Надо знать, какие компоненты используются, но автор не говорит.

Comment: Исправил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте селективную процедуру и не парьтесь. Ваши предположения о том, что 'нельзя', ошибочны. Главное, не забыть вызвать fetch для каждого возвращаемого значения. Точнее я бы вам сказал, если бы вы указали используемые компоненты.

Answer (score 0):

Не а, я восспользовался другим способом, функцией "list".
Дело в том, что у меня этот параметр можно сделать типа "string", таким образом можно весь результат вывести в **одну** строку через запятую:

> select **list(DEVICE_ID, ', ')**        from ...

но за ответ спасибо.